# cd into first/second/third directory returned by ls -d */

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, ls, cd

Say I am in a directory `code`:

```
/code
    /very-long-and-descriptive-name
```

If I want to `cd` into that directory (or a directory if it comes first in alphabetical order), I can just `cd *`.

Now say I add more directories and files to `code`:

```
/code
    ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS.md
    /a-very-long-directory-name
    /super-long-name-that-is-quite-long
    README.md
    /very-long-and-descriptive-name
```

Is there a way that I can `cd` into the (alphabetically ordered) first (a-very), 2nd (super-long) or third (very-long) directory quickly?

Like `cd */ 1`, `cd */ 2`, `cd */ 3`?

Comment: If you use `tab` key, it should try to auto-complete. So if you type `a` and `tab`, it will expand into `a-very-long..`, `s` and `tab` into `super-long...`, etc.

Comment: Wow. I did not know that at all and it solves the issue, so if you make that an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `tab` key, it should try to auto-complete. So if you type `a` and `tab`, it will expand into `a-very-long..`, `s` and `tab` into `super-long...`, etc